# MItSurfaceCV, how to get Indices?

Tags: python, maya, pymel, maya-api

I'm trying to get the SurfaceCV indices from a NurbsSurface.

When I use the MItSurfaceCV class I get too few indices.

My Code till now, with a NurbsSphere selected:

```
sel = om.MSelectionList()
om.MGlobal.getActiveSelectionList(sel, 0)

dg = om.MDagPath()
sel.getDagPath(0, dg)

cvIter = om.MItSurfaceCV(dg)

inds = []
while not cvIter.isDone():

    num1 = om.intPtr()
    num2 = om.intPtr()

    cvIter.getIndex(num1, num2)

    inds.append([num1.value(), num2.value()])

    cvIter.next()
```

My Output:

```
[0, 0]
[1, 0]
[2, 0]
[3, 0]
[4, 0]
[5, 0]
[6, 0]
```

But it should be:

```
[0,0]
[0,1]
...
[0,7]
[1,0]
[1,1]
...
[1,7]
[2,0]
...
[6,7]
```

Thanks to anyone looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ok when selecting a nurb's cvs:

```
import maya.OpenMaya as om

sel = om.MSelectionList()
om.MGlobal.getActiveSelectionList(sel, 0)

dg = om.MDagPath()
mComponent = om.MObject()  # Create MObject to contain selected components.
sel.getDagPath(0, dg, mComponent)  # Construct dag path and components.

cvIter = om.MItSurfaceCV(dg, mComponent)  # Include components in constructor.

inds = []

def appendIndexes():
    num1 = om.intPtr()
    num2 = om.intPtr()

    cvIter.getIndex(num1, num2)

    inds.append([num1.value(), num2.value()])

while not cvIter.isDone():
    while not cvIter.isRowDone():
        num1 = om.intPtr()
        num2 = om.intPtr()

        cvIter.getIndex(num1, num2)
        inds.append([num1.value(), num2.value()])

        cvIter.next()
    cvIter.nextRow()

print len(inds)
```

But for some reason it's iterating over extra out of range indexes when you have the object selected. I'm not too sure why..

[Here's an example of it being used](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/API/move_tool_8py-example.html). I'm not sure what else I'm missing, but hope that nudges you in the right direction.

Comment: Hey, yeah you're right. I also got that overhead of indices. No idea what's going on there. I've also tried `MFnNurbsSurface.numCVsinU` and it's counterpart but there's also an overhead.

Comment: Interesting enough that it seems to work ok once the nurbs degree is set as linear.